# Fetch Test data from Excel using TOSCA

Tags: automated-tests, tosca

This is about TOSCA Automation tool.

I have an excel and loaded all my test data in it.

All i need to do is getting this data from excel using TOSCA.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

There are two kind of scenarios that originate when you say you have your test data in excel.

Scenario #1: If you have a single test scenario that needs to be tested against different datasets, then TOSCA provides you with a very good feature of TemplateInstances, which will not only create the desired number of test cases for you from your data set but will also import your excel's data and embed it in Test Case steps. For more details, please see the documentation of TOSCA Commander on TemplateInstances.

Scenario #2: If you have different test cases and want to just import data from an external source then you can use the common modules provided by Tricentis along with standard TOSCA installation under the name Excel Engine. Alternatively, you can also write your own Keywords using VBScript and import your excel into TOSCA.

Answer (score 0):

TOSCA has its own **Excel engine** add-in which can be used as parametrization of data from excel workbook.

Other then that I've also searched on this topic and found some **Worx.tce** predefined module which we need to import as a subset, to use the excel as a test data provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you  want to use excel to fetch data for test scripts you can use excel module in standard module section provided by tosca and can use buffer as input type to store and data for later use OR you can use test sheet module where you can store data and can use it in future it would be more helpful as it will remove the dependency of excel file in your test scripts and handling test sheet is better way.